# How can I get meshes I generated in Blender to stop rotating some parts 90 degrees on import to other software?

Tags: export, bones, .fbx

thanks for taking the time to read my question.  I have a mesh that I've rigged and set up in Blender, and I'm exporting it as an FBX to use in other applications.  I use a program called Noesis to translate Blender's export into a version my target software, Poser, can read.  It looks fine in Noesis:

[image]

But when I import it into Poser, some (but not all) of the bones are rotated 90 degrees:

[image]

I can manually re-orient the bones and make it work, but I'd rather understand the problem.  Poser doesn't have any options when importing FBX files, so I'm hoping this is something I can fix on the Blender side.  Any idea how I can export an FBX without this result?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing all the details of your project, but often things like this amount to a Z-up vs a Y-up issue or something similar. For example, blender uses a Z-Up system as a basis for it's orientations, whereas something like Unity, uses Y-up. Usually there are settings to convert in the exporter, but you are saying there are no config options in the one you are using?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The only options Poser offers is to scale the imported FBX.

I've been experimenting with the axes, and while it does point the problem bones in different directions when I change these values, it doesn't do it correctly.